# how could I allow my customers to update my application

Tags: android

I have finished building an android application, I still have to do one last step, which is open a window for updating.

#### what I have thought about

there should be two scenarios:

- an important update, which means a new version contains a lot of different from the last update and I don't want my users to use the old version any more so in this case whenever the user open the application, he MUST update to the newest version in order to work with the application again. for instance, the newest version contains new functionality, or contains a new data representation.
- not important update, which means that the user should update the application but it is not a necessary step. for example, the newest version just contains more beautiful images.

#### my question

what is the best practice to allow my users to update the new version of the application.

In addition, I thing it is something about the URI which contains the package of the application in `play store`, for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

in that code, I allow my users to download the `Google Map`application from `play store`.

#### any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of server. This server would answer users if they have current version (answers: current, supported, outdated).

You can use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to inform client app that it should ask server about version.

App would ask server about version on start/resume/back online and when GCM arrives.

When app receive supported it can show users information about new version available. When it gets outdated it should lock until user updates it.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could just load your app onto Google Play and let that server notify (with it's already built-in GCM of sorts) when an update is ready.  You need to do nothing to ensure your users have access to updates, although you cannot force them into it